# Write function, which returns an unique identifier for parameter.(Java Script)

Tags: javascript, symbols

I have tried to do it, but all I get is that output: ---> Symbol(Test)
Is it even possible to get output like this(with single quotes in it): ---> Symbol('Test')

```js
function getUnique(param) {
    param = Symbol(param);
    return param;
} 

console.log(getUnique('Test')) // Symbol('Test') <--- I need to get that output
```

Comment: input and output are two different things. I think you use the words in a wrong meaning.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What does happen?

Comment: Sorry guys, I actually use words in a wrong meaning.
I need to get OUTPUT(console.log) like this --> | Symbol('Test') | 
With single quotes in it.

Comment: The representation of what gets printed at the console is implementation dependent and could even vary from version to version of the same implementation. Running it in latest chrome gives an output of `Symbol(Test)` and firefox gives `Symbol("Test")`. It's the same thing either way: the console printed output is just a *representation* of the thing. It isn't actually any different.

Comment: @JaredSmith Yup, thanks! Helped a lot!
I thought it`s me doing something wrong, and it`s some way to get Symbol output with single quotes, regardless version of browser.

Comment: @JaredSmith I`m kinda new to StackOverflow, how can I mark you comment as an answer? Or you can create an answer with the same text, and I will mark it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The representation of what gets printed at the console is implementation dependent and could even vary from version to version of the same implementation. Running it in latest chrome gives an output of Symbol(Test) and firefox gives Symbol("Test"). It's the same thing either way: the console printed output is just a representation of the thing. It isn't actually any different, it's still a unique Symbol 'Test'.

Answer (score 1):

**[Updated]** Not sure if this is what you want...

```js
function getUnique(param) {
    param = Symbol("'" + param + "'");
    return param;
} 

console.log(getUnique('Test'))
```

Comment: Nope. I need to get output as data type "Symbol" with label like this: 'Test". But thank you for trying to help!

Comment: Thanks, it`s the way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

I may be completely misunderstanding your question, but if you mean

> Symbol('Test') <--- I need to get that **output**

You can append the single quote characters to the string like so:

```js
const getUnique = (param) => {
  const sym = Symbol(param);
  return sym;
}

console.log(getUnique(`'test'`))
```

Comment: What gets printed to the console is actually implementation dependent. See my comment on the question. Your version only works "correctly" on chrome. Firefox output of your code is `Symbol("'test'")`

Comment: Thanks, it is one of solutions. But I meant to get output without any changes in the input. In another words: to get OUTPUT like this: |Symbol('Test')| with INPUT(to function) like this: | getUnique('Test') |.